# how to know which version of ruby on rails is through my cpanel no ssh access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cpanel, web-hosting

I have recently bought a cpanel account from a reseller.

In my cpanel home page, I have an icon to setup Ruby on Rails. And, also I want to use ruby on rails for my new websites. But I could not find any information for it's version.

So how can I know my Ruby on Rails installed version inside my cpanel?

Comment: While CPanel is used for hosting, it's not directly tied to application development. [su] would be a better fit for this question.

Comment: It should support bundler, so you can use rails version

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Rails::VERSION::STRING
```

It returns current version of rails gem

Comment: sorry, but I guess this means first I have to log in from terminal, isn't it?

Comment: @SuYo you can put this in some view and see that page to see